# RegEx : Perfect hash tag regex

Tags: javascript, regex, hash

**This is what I have so far:**

```
\s#([^ ]*)
```

**Example :** http://regexr.com?2te3d

It works pretty well except hashtags at the beginning of strings don't get picked up by my RegEx.

How should I modify it to pick these ones up as well? The \b command doesn't seem to work the same way as it does with normal words.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it is just about the beginning of the string, you could do:

```
(^|\s)#([^ ]*)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch pal! Works great. Today is my first day at attempting RegEx, still a little confusing!

Comment: But is capturing the previous whitespaces, any idea on how avoiding this?

Comment: @XaviColomer: Unfortunately, JavaScript has no lookbehind, but you can use a non capturing group: `(?:^|\s)#([^ ]*)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex: `\B#([^ ]+)`
It matches all hashtags except the one in the  URL which i guess shouldn't be matched

Comment: It seems to match the one in the url for me, which I don't really want. See here : http://regexr.com?2te3s

Answer (score 1):

Given this input: `#first #second # #third #weird#tag #with-minus #`

This: `/(^|\s)#([^\s]+)/g` will skip empty #'s and will only match:

- #first
- #second
- #third
- #weird#tag
- #with-minus

Comment: But is capturing the previous whitespaces, any idea on how avoiding this?